# Craps dice game simulator

Tags: python, game, random, dice

This craps game simulator is based on someone else's posted Python code that I've redone for practice. I'm interested in improving readability and making it more pythonic. I used `unittest` instead of `nose` because I'm using an online IDE.

```
from random import randrange
import unittest

class CrapsGame:
    def __init__(self):
        self.outcomes = {'2':False,'3':False,'12':False,'7':True,'11':True,
                '4&4':True,'5&5':True,'6&6':True,
                '8&8':True,'9&9':True,'10&10':True,
                '4&7':False,'5&7':False,'6&7':False,
                '8&7':False,'9&7':False,'10&7':False}

    def play(self, roll_dice):
        comeOut = str(roll_dice())
        print 'began game with ' + comeOut
        if comeOut in self.outcomes:
            return self.outcomes[comeOut]
        while True:
            point = str(roll_dice())
            print 'next roll is ' + point
            state = comeOut+'&'+point
            if state in self.outcomes:
                return self.outcomes[state]


class CrapsTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def testWinComeOut(self):
        game = CrapsGame()
        self.assertEquals(game.play(lambda: 7), True)

    def testLoseComeOut(self):
        game = CrapsGame()
        self.assertEquals(game.play(lambda: 2), False)

    def testWinPoint(self):
        game = CrapsGame()
        rollData = [5,6,5]
        self.assertEquals(game.play(lambda: rollData.pop()), True)

    def testLosePoint(self):
        game = CrapsGame()
        rollData = [7,5]
        self.assertEquals(game.play(lambda: rollData.pop()), False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Comment: I can give my 2 cents in regard to the naming conventions. Using snake case for the variables' names would be definitely more pythonic, for example `come_out` instead of `comeOut`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some general comments first.

1. There's no need to make your throws in strings for the outcomes - you can use tuples instead. e.g.

   ```
   self.outcomes = { (2,):False, (5,5):True }
   ```
2. If you pass a "wrong" set of dice throws (say \$[4,5]\$), you'll have an exception raised which isn't dealt with (and should probably be a test?).
3. `pop` removes the last element, which means you process them in reverse order - which differs from what the casual reader might expect (\$[7,5]\$ = 7 first, then 5).

You may want to look at generators which would provide a nice interface to a throw. In this case, what about:

```
class DiceThrow:
    def __init__( self, rolls = None ):
        self.rolls = rolls
    def First( self ):
        return self.__next__()
    def __iter__( self ):
        return self
    def __next__( self ):
        if self.rolls is not None:
            if len( self.rolls ) == 0:
                raise StopIteration
            r = self.rolls[0]
            self.rolls = self.rolls[1:]
            return r
        return randrange( 1, 13 ) # may be better as randint( 1, 12 )
```

This can then be called as follows:

```
game.play( DiceThrow( [5,7] ) )
game.play( DiceThrow() ) # for a random set of throws
```

and used:

```
def play(self, dice_throw):
    comeOut = dice_throw.First()
    print( "began game with %d"%comeOut )
    if (comeOut,) in self.outcomes:
        return self.outcomes[(comeOut,)]
    for point in dice_throw:
        print( "next roll is %d"%point )
        state = (comeOut,point)
        if state in self.outcomes:
            return self.outcomes[state]
    print( "Bad rolls!" )
```

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the effort. I like the tuples instead of strings, and the idea of using a generator sounds interesting.